# Using Postman raw to upload file to box api

Tags: file-upload, box-api, postman, box

I am fairly new to the box api and curl, so forgive me if the question seems little dim.

So after taking a look at the box api upload

```
curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" -X POST \
  -F attributes='{"name":"tigers.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"11446498"}}' \
  -F file=@myfile.jpg
```

I am trying to upload a local file ( c:\boxapitest.txt ) on to box through postman

file is uploaded on to box successfully when using the form-data from postman.

but

is there way to upload a local file from postman to box using raw?(postman maybe json object?)

I am trying to avoid using formdata and jquery due to the platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the Upload process does use a Multipart POST method when uploading the files. The approach in the example curl request is the simplest way to accomplish this, by referencing the file directly. This allows for basically a shortcut of not having to explicitly include the Content-Length and file data in the request.

Having said that, it does not mean that you can't pass in the file data in a more explicit way. For an example of how another user has built such a request you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819919/box-file-upload-not-setting-content-created-at-attribute-c-sharp). There, they are manually constructing an HTTP Upload request, including the file data within the request object itself. The Content-Type is still multipart/form-data for the overall request, but you can see how they are reading in the file data, and then explicitly including it as well as the Content-Length with the request.